# Subsets of $\mathbb{S}^n$ fixed by an orientation-reversing self-homeomorphism — Part 1

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Call a subset  $Z$ of $\mathbb{S}^n$ *ambiently-reversible*, if there is an orientation-reversing self-homeomorphism $h: \mathbb{S}^n \to \mathbb{S}^n$ fixing $Z$ pointwise.

**Question 1:** Which subsets of $\mathbb{S}^n, n \geq 2$ are ambiently-reversible?

This may be hard, so let me ask a more specific question:

**Question 2:** Let $Z \subset \mathbb{S}^2$ be closed. Is it true that $Z$ is ambiently-reversible iff it is homeomorphic with a subspace of $\mathbb{S}^1$?

An amusing excercise: show that $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is ambiently-reversible in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Note that if $Z$ is contained in a homeomorph $K$ of $\mathbb{S}^1$ where $K\subset \mathbb{S}^2$, then $Z$ is ambiently-reversible. To see this, apply Jordan-Shoenflies to $K$, and reflect its two sides. This can be used, in combination with the Denjoy–Riesz theorem, to show that every closed 0-dimensional subset of $\mathbb{S}^2$ is ambiently-reversible. (This solves the above excercise.)

Remark: If $Z$ is ambiently-reversible, then so is its closure.

See also [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428999/subsets-of-mathbbsn-fixed-by-an-orientation-reversing-automorphism-part).

Comment: You may want to assume $Z$ is closed, as otherwise a countable dense subset of $S^2$ will be a counterexample. Also, I don't see why you have split this question into two parts, it seems to me like the other part would be perfectly fine as a paragraph in this question.

Comment: @Wojowu: I've edited to require Z to be closed in Q2, thanks.

Comment: automorphism: for which structure? it you mean self-homeomorphism, why not say it rather than "automorphism"?

Comment: @YCor: yes, I mean self-homeomorphism, I've edited it, sorry.