# Subsets of $\mathbb{S}^n$ fixed by an orientation-reversing self-homeomorphism — Part 2

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

This is another special case of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428998/subsets-of-mathbbsn-fixed-by-an-orientation-reversing-automorphism-part).

Recall that we call a subset  $Z$ of $\mathbb{S}^n$ *ambiently-reversible*, if there is an orientation-reversing homeomorphism $h: \mathbb{S}^n \to \mathbb{S}^n$ fixing $Z$ pointwise.

**Question 1:** Is there an ambiently-reversible wild Cantor set in $\mathbb{S}^n, n\geq 3$? Is there a non-ambiently-reversible one?

Comment: To produce a reversible one is quite trivial. Just take $K$ wild Cantor with $K\cap -K$ empty, and consider $K\cup -K$.

Comment: @YCor: we want to fix $Z$ **pointwise**, so I don't see how your example is reversible.

Comment: Ah, indeed, I didn't notice "pointwise"

Comment: BTW, one can ask which subsets of $\mathbb{S}^n$ are setwise reversible, but I don't expect the answer to be nice.

Comment: I think there is an ambiently-reversible wild Canter set. Recall that R. H. Bing was the first to produce exotic involution of S^3 having wild fixed points. In particular, he showed that AH $\cup_{id}$ AH is homeomorphic to S^3, where AH denotes the crumpled 3-cube bounded by the Alexander horned sphere. One may have more examples by requiring that the crumpled cubes satisfy the Disjoint Disk Property.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the proof of the exercise problem in [Part 1 of the OP Question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428998/subsets-of-mathbbsn-fixed-by-an-orientation-reversing-self-homeomorphism), one may generalize it to higher dimensions. However, since the direct extension of Jordan-Schoenflies theorem is impossible, the generalization is not obvious. I think the OP is related to the problem of exotic involution of $S^n$. When $Z$ is a Cantor set, $Z$ can be considered as a closed subset of a wildly embedded sphere in $S^3$. the Alexander horned sphere $\Sigma$. $\Sigma$ separates $S^3$ and the closures of the corresponding components in the complement are [crumpled 3-cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crumpled_cube). Denote the crumpled 3-cube by $AH$. As I made in the comment, [R. H. Bing](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969804) stunned the community by showing that $AH \cup_{id} AH$ $\approx S^3$, the argument relies on his shrinking criterion. The point is that his result shows that $S^3$ admits an involution fixing a wild 2-sphere, the Alexander horned sphere $\Sigma$. Note that $Z \subset \Sigma$. Then $Z$ is ambiently-reversible.

This might be a rudimentary example to the OP. Because it seems that the OP requires that the Cantor set $Z$ is wild in $S^3$. The one in the Alexander horned sphere is not wild in $S^3$. Indeed, $Z$ is twice flat in the sense that it is flat both as a subset of the Alexander horned sphere and as a subset of $S^3$. However, there are results may handle Cantor sets which are wildly embedded in the ambient space. For instance, for any crumpled $n$-cube $C$, $n \geq 5$, $C ∪_{Id} C \approx S^n$ iff $C$ satisfies the Disjoint Disks Property. See [Thm 7.10.6, P. 413, Daverman-Venema](https://maths.dur.ac.uk/users/mark.a.powell/%5BDaverman-Venema%5D%20Embeddings%20in%20manifolds.pdf).

Using the involution of spheres alone might not answer whether there exists a non-ambiently-reversible Cantor set, a potential example is produced by [Daverman](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1387.57038). Utilizing a sticky Cantor set in $S^n$ ($n\geq 4$) constructed by Krushkal, he showed that the sewings of some crumpled cubes $C \cup_{Id} C$ is not homeomorphic to sphere. Furthermore, there is no homeo $H: Bd C \to Bd C$ close to $Id$ such that $C \cup_{H} C \approx S^n$.